# Instrument bar disappeared

Tags: internet-explorer

I am unfortunately obliged to Internet Explorer and the instrument bar is disappeared.
I don't know how to restore it.
If I want to (e.g.) load a file I don't know how to load it because I don't know how to restore the bar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not one hundred percent sure what you mean by "Instrument bar" and you don't specify what version of IE you're using but since you mention opening files I'm guessing you mean the menu bar. In the newer versions of IE (say 7+) If you go to Tools > Toolbars and then click on Menu Bar I think you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I meant the menu bar.
If I go to tools, there isn't the option "toolbar".
I am really trying to guess how could they think that an user doesn't need to save files, import bookmarks, etc... mystery.

Comment: So I still have that problem: there isn't any option "toolbar" if I click on the tools icon.

Comment: If I right click anywhere around the tabs or favorites bar I get the list of toolbars in the context dialogue. They can then be clicked on and off through that.